# How to move TOC at the top of article like Wikitravel in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

How to move TOC at the top of article like Wikitravel in MediaWiki, applying for all pages? Which extensions or settings need for this action?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
#toc, .toc { float: left; }
```

in your `MediaWiki:Vector.css` or `MediaWiki:Common.css`